# how to get data in Custom property based on Complex type property in EntityFramework Code first approach

Tags: ef-code-first

Hi all I am new to Code first approach and complex type in Entity framework (version 5). I am working on some functionality where i have to fetch data based on property in complex type, I tried many ways but could not succeed. below are the details on my implementation.

**Database MainTable1 =>**
int IDField1_Maintbl [Primarykey], int Filed2, ..., varchar Fieldn

I have another detail table

**Database DetailTable1** =>
int IDField1 [PrimaryKey],int IDField1_Maintbl[ForeignKey], varchar Field2, varchar Field3, int A_IDField4, varchar A_Field5, varchar A_Field6, ..., varchar Field10,

the last table on which I am working is as below
**Table2 =>**
int A_IDField4 [PrimaryKey], varchar Field2_tbl2, bool? Field3_tbl2,

here I have relation between Table2 and DetailTable1 as 1:M in database based on Table2.A_IDField4 and DetailTable1.A_IDField4 fields.

Respective Entities in C# are as below:

```
public classEntityForMainTable1
{
    public int IDField1_Maintbl  {get;set;}
    public int Filed2 {get;set;}
    ...
    public varchar Fieldn {get;set;}
    public IList<EntityForDetailTable1> table1Data{get;set;}
}
public class EntityForDetailTable1
{
    public int IDField1 {get;set;}
    public string Field2 {get;set;}
    public string Field3 {get;set;}
    public string AField7 {get;set;}
    ...
    public string Field10 {get;set;}
    public Table1ComplexType tble1ct {get;set;}
}
public class EntityTable2
{
    public int A_IDField4  {get;set;}
    public string Field2_tbl2 {get;set;}
    public bool? Field3_tbl2 {get;set;}
}
public class DetailTable1ComplexType //Complex Type
{
    public int A_IDField4  {get;set;}
    public string A_Field5 {get;set;}
    public string A_Field6 {get;set;}
}
```

OnModelCreating method is as below:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<classEntityForMainTable1>().ToTable("MainTable1", "Custom");
    modelBuilder.Entity<EntityForDetailTable1>().ToTable("DetailTable1", "Custom");
    modelBuilder.Entity<EntityTable2>().ToTable("Table2", "Custom");
    RegDetailTable1ComplexType.Register(modelBuilder); //RegDetailTable1ComplexType is a static class that register the complex type.

}
```

What my requirement is; I have to add custom property in EntityForDetailTable1 as :

```
public bool? Field3_tbl2 {get;set;}
```

This property should return value of **Field3_tbl2** from Table **Table2** depend on value of **A_IDField4** from entity **DetailTable1ComplexType** and **EntityTable2**

Any help would appriciated.